# jquery makes the browser display 'connecting'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I copied and later on modified the code below.
It displays the 'JQuery's Hello, World!' string on the web page. Briefly displaying 'Out of JQuery'; I mean it disappears almost immediately. And the code ends processing leaving the browser running on a sort of loop saying 'connecting' on the tab.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!---******* HEAD *******-->
<head>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
    <title>Testing JQuery</title>
</head>

<!---******* BODY *******-->
<body>
    <title>The jQuery Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Java enabled: " + navigator.javaEnabled());
    </script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            document.write("JQuery's Hello, World!");
        });
    </script>       
    <p> Out of JQuery </p> <!-- Does not display -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't see the problem

Comment: Side note, the `<title>` must be within the head of the document. Also, the code you posted doesn't exhibit the behavior you claim.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `Out of Jquery` briefly displays then disappears is because calling `document.write` on an already loaded document clears the current document:

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, which will clear the document.

As for your other problem I can't recreate it.